# Cannot post question, code not properly formatted?

Tags: bug

One more person who may not submit his question because of accusations of improperly formatted code. Offending Markdown:

Based on [this answer][sx-question], I wanted to implement sidenotes on a blog using a CSS flex box. I ended up with this HTML code:

```
    <style>
      article {width: 66%;}
      aside {width: 33%;}

      .lfloat {flex: 1; float: left;}
      .rfloat {flex: 1; float: right;}

      .pwn {display: flex;}
    </style>

    <section>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
      </p>

      <p class="pwn">
        <article class="lfloat">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        </article>

        <aside class="rfloat">
          This is just a small comment
        </aside>
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
      </p>
    </section>

Instead of getting a sidenote with the same height, [safari][safari] begins the
next paragraph directly under the sidenote, adjacent to the other paragraph.
[Vivaldi][vivaldi] does even quirkier by moving the "L" before sidenote and
resuming the next line with "orem ipsum...".
(Links are pictures of the rendered output by both browsers)

Questions:

- Is my code bad or is the feature implementation of the browsers causing me this issue?
- How could I fix the issue, so that it renders robustly at least on FF, Safari, IE and anything based chromium?


[sx-question]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669539/7525350
[safari]: https://ibb.co/cyTwrv
[vivaldi]: https://ibb.co/fdBGrv
```

Many answers on Meta about previous questions say that you should format code with Markdown, not with direct HTML, which I did. Others told that there are sometimes problems with headings, of which I have none, and one reported an issue with a sentence ending in a semicolon. And while I have my `Questions:`-line ending in a colon, removing this wouldn't allow me to post my question either.

PS/Edit: No problems posting it here. Is this because the rules are less strict on meta, or is it because I indented my whole post by 4 lines?

Edit 2: It seems to have to do with reputation; see the comments of @CodyGray and @Stijn. Hopefully someone working on the detection algorithm and/or the implementation that links reputation to the required level of code markup stumbles across here, as this is hugely frustrating.

Comment: Hmm. I had no trouble posting what you've shown here, so either the rules are relaxed at a certain reputation level, or something else is wrong. I don't have a low-reputation sockpuppet that I can test with.

Comment: @CodyGray could you just send me the link to the posted question? That would at least help me to answer the question. As is elaborated in the question that Stijn linked, it seems that it almost certainly has to do with reputation, and I am really stuck with my original question for now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I deleted it immediately after it posted correctly, so that won't be very helpful for you. I don't see any problems with what you have here, so I don't know what could possibly be tripping up the filter.

Comment: Okay...yeah, I also repro this as an anonymous user trying to suggest an edit to a question, replacing all its text. It's the way you've formatted the links. Quick workaround is to just use `[link text](http://example.com)`. Those brackets must be confusing things. If I change one of them (like the Vivaldi one), then I can submit it just fine.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, at least, the error message is gone now. Just have to wait 90 minutes until I can post a new question lol.